# Change href value in android to local one using JSoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

How can I change the value of href in HTML code of some page stored locally in Android?

```
 private void changeHrefsToLocal(String pageName) throws IOException {

    File input = new File(appContext.getFilesDir(), pageName);
    Document savedDoc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
    Elements links = savedDoc.select("a[href]");

    String href;

    for(Element link : links){

                href = appContext.getFilesDir() + "/" + link.attr("abs:href").replace(INDEX_URL, "") + ".html";
                link.attr("href",  href);

            }
    }
```

Logs:

```
11-23 18:40:33.837 10380-10397/com.pokropek.ernest.protectedofflinewebviewer E/testing: <a href="http://test.pl/kontakt">Kontakt</a>

11-23 18:40:33.837 10380-10397/com.pokropek.ernest.protectedofflinewebviewer E/testing: <a href="/data/data/com.pokropek.ernest.protectedofflinewebviewer/files/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
```

If I print the link to the logs before and after the method runs, there's the expected change, although there's **no change in the local .html file**, which is the main problem.

Comment: Welcome. How are you printing those logs? Your code doesn't include the part that you actually save your changes back to the file. Maybe you miss that?

Comment: Thanks Bruno, that's a really good point. I indeed missed writing those changes to the file. As I understand, the link.attr(...) doesn't impact the file I'm working on, since it is a different document/set of links copied from the document? If that's so, how can I commit those changes to the local file?

Comment: My pleasure :) Maybe you should check the docs for JSoup on how to save a Document back to a file? I know nothing about JSoup, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Its simple just save the edited html file back.

Here is the sample code

```
    File input = new File(appContext.getFilesDir(), pageName);
    Document savedDoc = null;
    try {
        savedDoc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error ",  e.toString());
    }

    Elements links = savedDoc.select("a[href]");

    for(Element link : links){
        link.attr("href", "changed value");//change the value of href attribute here
    }

    //save the updated/edited html file
    PrintWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(input,"UTF-8");
        writer.write(savedDoc.html() ) ;
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error ", e.toString());
    }
```